# Carapaces in Neal Asher's Polity universe - turtles?

Tags: polity-agent, polity-universe

What do humans wearing the carapaces really look like?

*Another form of Haimain (Human-AI hybrid) in Neal Asher's Polity universe (Agent Cormac novels specifically) are humans wearing the "carapace and sensory cowl".*

In the book [Polity Agent: An Agent Cormac Novel 4](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/511226.Polity_Agent) which I am currently reading, Orlandine took over Shoala's carapace to kill him in a most gruesome manner by pushing mechanical legs inside him! This image really sticks with me.

The "legs" are described as insectile, so if I think about what it looks like when people use them, I think about poor Gregor Samsa from [Kafka's The Metamorphosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Metamorphosis).

The carapace idea also reminds me of Prador and their shells.

However, the strongest image I get in my head is [Dana Carvey in The Master of Disguise: am I not turtley enough for the turtle club?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezAJeaCySV4) It seems so silly!

What do they do with their human arms and legs while using the carapace arms? Are people really scuttling about like insects? With such amazing miniaturisation evident in the books, what do they really need "shells" for?